# Multiple choice question about the roots of a cubic equation

Tags: polynomials, roots, cubics

I am in class $7$th and studying high school maths. I encountered the following question. How can I solve it?

[image: Question]

Well I have eliminated option **A** and **B** by using the concept that sum of roots in cubic equation is equal to $b/a$ and product of the roots is $d/a$. Here is my working:

> $$x^2-ax^2-bx+c=0$$
> Let the roots be $j$, $k$, and $l$. Then,
> \begin{align}
> j + k + l &= a \\
> jkl &= -c \\
> jk + kl + lj &= -b
> \end{align}

Comment: What does $a,b,c\in \mathbb I$ mean?

Comment: I appreciate that it's not nice being downvoted, but if you want to avoid this then please show your working.

Comment: @lulu I think that symbol is occasionally used to mean integers, but you'll have to check with the OP.

Comment: @Joe I am new to this platform so can you tell where to show my working

Comment: @Iulu it means that a, b and c all are integers

Comment: You show your work by typing it up in the question showing how far you have gotten.  There are links in the FAQ to MathJax for formatting the math.  You are expected to look up the Cardano solution for the roots of a cubic and see what the information about the coefficients tells you.  Have you looked it up?

Comment: Ok.  That is usually denoted $\mathbb Z$, just for reference.  But...what have you tried?  Can you eliminate any of the options?

Comment: @RaviShami To show your working, edit your question. Below the blue tags that say 'polynomials, roots, cubic equations', there are a few buttons, one of which says 'Edit'. Click on it.

Comment: Have you been taught Vieta's formulas?

Comment: @Joe I have now shown my working

Comment: @shortmanikos See I am just in grade 7 and I am studying high concept maybe I might be using it but not knowing but as far I haven't heard this formula.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

x1 + x2 + x3 =-a and x1*x2*x3 =-c

This means that

x1 + x2 + x3 >0
x1*x2*x3 <0

This is possible when two roots are greater than 0, and one less than 0

Comment: are you sure it will be x1 + x2 + x3 > 0 shouldn't it be x1 + x2 + x3 < 0

Comment: x1 + x2 + x3 = -a, if a<0, then x1 + x2 +x3 >0

Comment: well actually you should make it x1 + x2 + x3 is a then it would be correct

Comment: The sum of roots equals -a

Answer (score 0):

Since OP indicates that they are in a high school course, it may be that the question only intended that the students use Descartes' Rule of Signs.  If we include the signs of the coefficients described in the problem statement, we have
$$ s(x) \ = \ x^3 - ax^2 - bx + c $$
and
$$ s(-x) \ = \ (-x)^3 - a(-x)^2 - b(-x) + c \  = \  -x^3 - ax^2 + bx + c \ \ . $$

If we scan along the coefficients in each expression, we note that the sign of the coefficients changes twice in $ \ s(x) \ $ (positive to negative and back again), while the sign only changes once in $ \ s(-x) \ $ (negative to positive).  The Rule tells us that there are either two or zero positive zeroes for this polynomial and one negative zero.

The "hedging" in Descartes' Rule is due to the fact that these sign changes *cannot* tell us about irreducible quadratic factors of the polynomial which would have *complex* zeroes.  However, a further condition in the problem is that the zeroes are all integers: this is stronger than strictly necessary, as it will suffice to make our choice to know that *all of the zeroes are real.*  Consequently, we now know that the polynomial as specified has two positive and one negative real zero; this corresponds to choice $ \ \mathbf{(D)} \ \ . $

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the solutions to the cubic $x^3+ax^2+bx+c$ are $r_1$, $r_2$, $r_3$. The the factored form of the equation is

$$(x-r_1)(x-r_2)(x-r_3)=0$$

Expanding the equation gives

$$x^3-(r_1+r_2+r_3)x^2+(r_1r_2+r_1r_3+r_2r_3)x-r_1r_2r_3=0$$

Since it’s given that $a,b\lt0$ and $c\gt0$,

$$r_1+r_2+r_3\gt0$$
$$r_1r_2+r_1r_3+r_2r_3\gt0$$
$$r_1r_2r_3\lt0$$

The first and third conditions are enough to determine the answer. For the product of the roots to be negative, either one root is negative or all three roots are negative. If the sum of the roots is positive, then all the roots can’t be negative.

Therefore, one root is negative, the other two are positive. (D)

Note: relabeling coefficients so that a, b, c are positive is fine, but you have to be careful to keep track of that change. It can cause confusion. In this case, the coefficients were only needed to set up the inequalities. They constraint didn’t really matter until the end.